# Airflow web: Pass program arguments to DAG as an array or list

Tags: python, airflow

I am pretty new to Airflow.
I have an airflow environment set up and all my services are being triggered fine by airflow. But, I intend to pass program arguments to one of the services defined in my DAG directly from airflow web. I see the following option on airflow web [**Trigger DAG w/ conf**]

[image]

I would like to pass a json as shown below as my program argument to my DAG:

```
{"list_key" : ["K1" : "V1", "K2" : "V2"]}
```

Once I pass the program argument as shown above, how would I be able to access this on my DAG? My DAG [python] code is as follows but it throws an error:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocSubmitJobOperator
from helper import help
import pendulum

config = help.loadJSON("config/loc")

# This is causing an error
args = list({{ dag_run.conf['list_key'] }})

common_task_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False
    # A few more configurations
}

dag = DAG('my-dag',
          default_args=common_task_args,
          is_paused_upon_creation=True,
          catchup=False,
          schedule_interval=None)

MY_TASK = {
    "reference": {"project_id": "project-id"},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": "cluster-name"},
    "pyspark_job": {
        "main_python_file_uri": config["pyspark_uri"],
        "properties": config["spark_properties"],
        # This is where I need to pass the program arguments
        "args": args
    }
}

my_task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    job=MY_TASK,
    dag=dag
)

my_task
```

The error is as follows:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/batch/my_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/batch/my_dag.py", line 12, in <module>
    args = list({{ dag_run.conf['list_key'] }})
NameError: name 'dag_run' is not defined
```

Shouldn't "dag_run" be made available by default to the DAG [that is what airflow web say]? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"but it throws an error"* - what is the error?  Hard for us to diagnose the issue without that.

Comment: @0x5453 Oops my bad. I have added it now. Thank you.

Comment: I see at least a couple problems: 1) In this snippet you haven't defined any DAGs or Tasks.  The `dag_run` variable can only be used inside of a Task context.  2) You can't use the template syntax (`{{}}`) just anywhere.  It only works inside of templated Operator fields, and those fields must be specified as strings.  For example, I would expect this to work: `BashOperator(task_id='foo', bash_command='echo {{dag_run.conf["list_key"]}}')`

Comment: @0x5453 Thank you for your response. I have edited my question to incorporate the entirety of my DAG code. I have also suggested where my program arguments must be passed. Could you please correct my mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

You just can't place jinja code anywhere in the dag file, it needs to be placed in an operator's template fields.

If you check out the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L1778), you can see that `job` is a template field. So you should be able to fix your code by having

```
my_task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    job = {
        "reference": {"project_id": "project-id"},
        "placement": {"cluster_name": "cluster-name"},
        "pyspark_job": {
            "main_python_file_uri": config["pyspark_uri"],
            "properties": config["spark_properties"],
            "args": list("{{ dag_run.conf['list_key'] }}")
        }
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

If you want a cleaner approach, you can also add a PythonOperator task which sets the MY_TASK variable.

```
MY_TASK = None
def make_task_fn(**kwargs):
    global MY_TASK
    MY_Task = {
        "reference": {"project_id": "project-id"},
        "placement": {"cluster_name": "cluster-name"},
        "pyspark_job": {
            "main_python_file_uri": config["pyspark_uri"],
            "properties": config["spark_properties"],
            "args": list(kwargs["dag_run"].conf["list_key"])
        }
    }

make_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='make_task',
    python_callable=make_task_fn,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

my_task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    job=MY_TASK,
    dag=dag
)

make_task >> my_task
```

Comment: I did try the first approach, but I get the following error: ***my_spark.py : error: unrecognized arguments: {{ dag_run.conf['list_key'] }}***

Comment: Add quotes around the  brackets ie "{{...}}"

Comment: It was with quotes. basically the same syntax as provided by you. Unfortunately it did not work.